# XmlHttpRequest Timeout - Property or Method Not Found

Tags: com, vbscript, timeout, xmlhttprequest

Attempting to make an http post to a web service from a basicscript (VBScript/VBA scripting language - SummitSoftware) and want to implement a timeout.

Apparently the XmlHttpRequest object has a timeout property (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535874%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but attempting to use it returns me a "property or method not found" error.

Eg:

```
Dim obj As Object
Set obj = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0")
obj.timeout = 123
```

This also applies to Microsoft.XMLHTTP and any other versions of the MSXML2 variant.

My only thought so far is to kick of another process which runs a vbscript to make the request. If it runs for more than a given time, kill the process. Not exactly ideal however.

Any ideas on this, or how this might be implemented differently?

**Edit (possible solutions):**

1. WShell.Run a VBScript to run in another process and complete the operation async. Kill if runs for more than n.
2. Use HTTP/1.1 Keep-Alive header. Would rather implement this on the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using VBA/VB6 or VBScript? In VBScript, `Dim obj As Object` is not valid as there is no static typing.

I think you might be looking at the wrong object reference. The `MSXML2.XMLHTTP` object has the `IXMLHTTPRequest` interface which is defined [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms760305%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and the [reference you mention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms760305%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is for the `XmlHttpRequest` object supported by Internet Explorer 7+.

Comment: It's actually BasicScript (a VBA compatable scripting language from Summit with VSTA - http://www.google.com.au/search?q=summit basicscript), edited to reflect this. The interaction is via COM, so i figure it's equiv for the purposes of this discussion. Thanks for the links, I was looking at the object docs, not the interface. That makes a bit more sense.

Answer (score 0):

I use this in vbscript:
oXMLHTTP.setTimeouts 60000,60000,60000,60000
to place before the OPEN
doc (mutatis mutandis for syntax):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms760403%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
hope it helps, surely to late :-) ...